# Induction of topological space by an $L^2$-space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, lp-spaces, measurable-functions

Let $(L^2(\Xi,\boldsymbol{\Xi},\mu;\mathbb{R}),\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle)$ be a Hilbert space, where $L^2(\Xi,\boldsymbol{\Xi},\mu;\mathbb{R})$ denotes the set of all (equivalence classes of) $\boldsymbol{\Xi}$-measurable $\mathbb{R}$-valued functions that are square $\mu$-integrable on $\Xi$, and $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle:L^2(\Xi,\boldsymbol{\Xi},\mu;\mathbb{R})\times L^2(\Xi,\boldsymbol{\Xi},\mu;\mathbb{R})\to\mathbb{R}$ denotes its standard inner product given by
$$\langle f,g\rangle=\int fg\,\mathrm{d}\mu.$$
I know that this Hilbert space induces a topological space whose induced standard topology $\mathcal{O}$ is the one generated by all open balls whose radii are measured using the induced standard metric $d:L^2(\Xi,\boldsymbol{\Xi},\mu;\mathbb{R})\times L^2(\Xi,\boldsymbol{\Xi},\mu;\mathbb{R})\to\mathbb{R}_0^+$ given by
$$d(f,g)=\langle f-g,f-g\rangle^{\tfrac{1}{2}}.$$
My question is how to write this standard topology symbolically.

At the moment I have defined the topological basis:
$$\mathscr{B}=\{B_r(f)\subset L^2(\Xi,\boldsymbol{\Xi},\mu;\mathbb{R})\,\mid\, r\in\mathbb{R}^+,f\in L^2(\Xi,\boldsymbol{\Xi},\mu;\mathbb{R})\},$$
where $B_r(f):=\{g\in L^2(\Xi,\boldsymbol{\Xi},\mu;\mathbb{R})\mid d(f,g)<r\}$ is the open ball of radius $r$ centered at $f$.

Then, we define $\mathcal{O}=\varphi(\mathscr{B})$. Here $\varphi$ represents a map which takes a topological basis as an input and returns a topology as an output. In measure theory, we have the map $\sigma$ which generates a $\sigma$-algebra from a given collection of subsets. I thought that the same could be done here. However, I haven't found the actual symbol for performing such an operation on a topological basis yet.

So, is this the correct way to write the induced standard topology symbolically? Also, is there a better way to write the same thing?

Thank you, Frederick.

Comment: Open set are not just open balls. The topology consists of all possible unions of sets in $\mathcal O$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks for the reply. The standard topology I am referring to here is the one that consists of all open balls. If not wrong, this is what a standard topology always refers to if nothing else is said.

Comment: What you've written down is what is called a [base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_%28topology%29) for a topology. From that you get the full topology by taking all possible unions of sets in your basis. Think back to $\mathbb R^2$: the set of all open balls is not the same as the set of all open subsets, it's for example missing $]0,1[ \times ]0,1[$.

Comment: @kahen Thanks for the clarification. Now I see what is wrong with my argument... How do we then write the topology generated by a basis symbolically? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a set $X$, a collection $\mathscr{B}$ of subsets of $X$ must satisfy two conditions to be a topological basis:

$1$. For any $x \in X$, there is $B\in \mathscr{B}$ such that $x \in B$.

$2$. For any $B_1, B_2 \in \mathscr{B}$ and for any $x \in B_1 \cap B_2$, there is a $B_3 \in  \mathscr{B}$ such that $x \in B_3$.

The topology generated by $\mathscr{B}$ is **usually** indicated by $\tau(\mathscr{B})$ (but this notation is not as standard as the $\sigma$ for the generated $\sigma$-algebra). Using this notation, we have:

$\tau(\mathscr{B})$ is the collection of arbitrary union of sets is $\mathscr{B}$.

So, while any collection of subsets can be used to generate a $\sigma$-algebra, it is not true that any collection of subsets is a basis for a topology.

If you want to mimic the concept of "generated $\sigma$-algebra" closer, you should use the concept of topological subbase:

Given a set $X$ and any collection $\mathscr{S}$ of subsets of $X$, the generated topology, $\tau(\mathscr{S})$, is defined as:

$\tau(\mathscr{S})$ is the collection of arbitrary unions of finite intersections of sets in $\mathscr{S}$.

Note that a partiular case of  finite intersection of sets in $\mathscr{S}$ is the nullary intersection who result is $X$.  So $X \in \mathscr{S}$.

In your specific example, $X= L^2(\Xi,\boldsymbol{\Xi},\mu;\mathbb{R})$ and we have that

$$\mathscr{B}=\{B_r(f)\subset L^2(\Xi,\boldsymbol{\Xi},\mu;\mathbb{R})\,\mid\, r\in\mathbb{R}^+,f\in L^2(\Xi,\boldsymbol{\Xi},\mu;\mathbb{R})\}$$
is actually a basis for the topology (the standard Hilbert space topology).

You could write $\tau(\mathscr{B})$ to indicate the generated topology.